# Odoo[12.0] : How to create dropdown and show all menus in dropdown and also will be select multiple menus

Tags: user-interface, menu, hide, dropdown, odoo-12

i want to create one [hide menu] dropdown field in user creation form. then after show all the menus in the dropdown field and we can also select multiple menus at a time. then which menu we selected they will be hide for the particular user. how to do this if you know it please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This capability is available in odoo itself but the module cannot access.
Enable debug. Go to technical in the settings section, edit the models, and access them there.

Comment: Hello, I'm talking about menus not a models. i want all menus in dropdown list.

Comment: For menus, go from technical to menus and give access.

Comment: use _fields.Many2one(comodel_name="ir.ui.menu")_ for get menus selection lists.

Comment: Hi. you know how to make relationship between res.user and all menus if you know please let me know. Thanks in Advanced

Answer (score 0):

By default in odoo menus is depend on groups which group you are selecting for user and groups is realted with menus but according to your requirement it is also possible but you have to do modifications for that firstly you have to make relationship between user and menus (res.user and ir.ui.menu) in which you select the menus which user can see and after that there is a default function which is called during menu load you can override it and show menus according to your choice to the user.